# No matching version found for child_process@^0.0.1

Tags: npm-package

i went to instatll node-telegram-bot-api pkg by using  ( npm i node-telegram-bot-api ) but i getting error , anyone know how to fix this ?

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for child_process@^0.0.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\gnome\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-26T11_51_31_687Z-debug-0.log

in log file : 88 verbose type range
89 verbose stack child_process: No matching version found for child_process@^0.0.1.
89 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-pick-manifest\lib\index.js:209:23)
89 verbose stack     at RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:119:22)
89 verbose stack     at async #nodeFromEdge (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1049:19)
89 verbose stack     at async #buildDepStep (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:917:11)
89 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:196:7)
89 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
89 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
89 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:149:5)
89 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
90 verbose cwd C:\Users\gnome
91 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
92 verbose node v20.4.0
93 verbose npm  v9.7.2
94 error code ETARGET
95 error notarget No matching version found for child_process@^0.0.1.
96 error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
96 error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
97 verbose exit 1
98 timing npm Completed in 21885ms
99 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1690371712674
100 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1690371712689
101 verbose code 1
102 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\gnome\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-26T11_41_49_827Z-debug-0.log

im not sure shoul i use npm in node.exe  app or not can do it on windows terminal since i already have node.exe set up on path but i already tried it on windows terminal